# Why does my water heater stop after a few minutes?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I have a Junkers (European water heater) that works for a few minutes and then stops. Anyone have experience with this/know how I can troubleshoot?

Or, would a regular plumber be able to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out someone had placed a board that was blocking the junkers' vent, so the thing was doing auto-shut-off to prevent over-heating. It's working fine now!